# flutter TexView - Insert values to raw strings

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the flutter package flutter_tex [(Link)](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex) working.
It renders fine, but I am not able to put my own values into the formula.

Example (factorB is the variables name):

```
String second = r"<br> $$x={\sqrt{factorB}}$$";
```

Result:
[image: result]

I also tried the $-operator before the variable like in a dart string, but because a raw string is needed, this doesn't work.
Is there a way to implement variable values in a raw string with this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not strictly necessary to use a raw string. Doing so just makes it more convenient to type all the back slashs and brackets required in LaTeX code.

You could always work with regular string, this just makes it more incovenient to produce correct LaTeX. Instead, I would suggest manually replacing the placeholder:

```
int number = 42;
String latex = r"<br> $$x={\sqrt{factorB}}$$";
latex = latex.replaceAll("factorB", number.toString());
```

If you would like to support more advanced interpolation via expressions,
I would recommend placing all of that logic inside the `replace` method. This here is an example

```
int factorB = 17;
int factorB = 1;    
String latex = r"exprA(x${exprB}$exprC)²exprD";
latex = latex.replaceAll("exprA", 42);
latex = latex.replaceAll("exprB", factorB >= 0 ? "+" : "");
latex = latex.replaceAll("exprC", factorC >= 0 ? "+" : "");
latex = latex.replaceAll("exprD", 33);
```

Comment: Is it further possible to use an inline statement like                                                  factorA(x${factorB >= 0 ? "+" : ""}$factorB)²${factorC >= 0 ? "+" : ""}$factorC  ? I used it to clearify if the numbers are positive or negative in an equation.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a solution for that szenario. If your question is answered, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left side. This helps others to see, that this question has already been answered